# ApolloGraphQL: useSubscription Hook Syntax with onSubscriptionData?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to build an Apollo `useSubscription` hook that uses `onSubscriptionData`.

I've looked [in the Apollo docs,](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/) but I haven't yet an example.

E.g. something like:

```
const { loading, error, data } = useSubscription(
    INCOMING_MESSAGES_SUBSCRIPTION_QUERY,
    {
        variables: {"localUserId": Meteor.userId()},
        onSubscriptionData: myFunctionThatRunsWhenSubscriptionDataArrives
    }
);
```

That can't be right yet, because it doesn't include `OnSubscriptionDataOptions<TData>`, which is mentioned in the Apollo docs.

What is the correct way to build a `useSubscription` hook that uses `onSubscriptionData`?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you asking what is the `OnSubscriptionDataOptions` type mentioned in the docs?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to get a code sample showing the syntax for using `onSubscriptionData` in a `useSubscription` hook. It would be great if the code sample could include `OnSubscriptionDataOptions`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `onSubscriptionData` function is passed a single `options` parameter of the type `OnSubscriptionDataOptions`. The `options` object has two properties:

- `client` -- the ApolloClient instance used to query the server
- `subscriptionData` -- an object with the following properties: `loading`, `data`, `error`

Example usage:

```
const { loading, error, data } = useSubscription(
  INCOMING_MESSAGES_SUBSCRIPTION_QUERY,
  {
    variables: {"localUserId": Meteor.userId()},
    onSubscriptionData: ({ subscriptionData: { data } }) => {
      // do something with `data` here
    }
  },  
)
```

Comment: Can i call subscription after another API call, what am trying to is i need to call subscription once i get a particular value from another API call

Comment: can you answer my quesiton here         
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67710167/call-usesubscription-after-a-button-click-or-after-a-variable-update